# How to pass URL as parameter in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass an URL from jsp to controller on a button submit

JSP Code:

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.location='<c:url value="/tools/serverLogs/${logsPath}/"/>'" name="serverLogsPage" value="View all logs"/>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/tools/serverLogs/{logsPath}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLogs( Model m, @PathVariable String logsPath) { 
 return "tools/ServerLogs";
}
```

I tried passing the path in different formats, but i am getting error while going to the controller.

Example:

logsPath = "C:\abc\def\ght";

logsPath = "C:\abc\def\ght"  (In this case i am not getting any error but in controller the path looks like C: abc def ght);

logsPath = "C://abc//def//ght";

logsPath = "file://abc/def/ght";

Comment: Seems like an issue with your escape characters...?

Comment: What do you really receive in other samples above?

Comment: I am getting 404 error while refreshing the page. I think this is because the <C:URL> is going to be like this "/tools/serverLogs/C:/abc/def/ght", and there is no method in the controller for this URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encode the logsPath before passing it on the view and decode it when retrieving content

```
logsPath = "C:\abc\def\ght";
logsPath = URLEncoder.encode(logsPath, "UTF-8"); // Or "ISO-8859-1"
```