# How to show the content of a log file in new window when we click on a link in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

My main goal: When i click the link, a new browser window should be opened and displays the content of entire log file. And the window should not have an address bar and navigation buttons (Back, Forward).

Is there any approach to do this in Spring-MVC project?
Here is what i am doing now:

1. When i click the link, the controller will be called with a parameter `logName`.
2. Now the controller have access to get any kind of details of the log file like content, path, etc... I am setting all these details to an object and sending back to JSP.

Here i am not sure how to open a new window and display the content of the log file in that window.

Please suggest me an approach on this!!
It would be very helpful for me if you can share me with some examples...

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923224/how-to-pass-object-as-parameter-to-java-script-function-on-onclick and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905184/how-to-pass-url-as-parameter-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring or JSP have nothing to do with it, the only way to force user's browser to open a link in a new tab is to use client-side Javascript. `window.open()` allows configuring the popup to hide certain interface elements (see all options in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features))

Your code would look something like:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Log" onclick="showLog(logName)">

function showLog(logName) {
    var url = "/path-to-your-controller.html?logName=" + logName;
    window.open(url, "LogPage", "toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no");
}
```

---

However, I don't think using a customised browser popup is a good solution; it's been disappearing from the web for a reason. It would be more elegant to fetch raw data using AJAX and display  it in a JS popup: it wouldn't interfere with user's page navigation (you tagged the question with jQuery, you could use jQuery UI for that).

What is more, I wouldn't be surprised if `window.open` wasn't supported by all browsers in the same way† - something to keep in mind if you're targeting a wider audience.

† *seems that Chrome ignores `location=no`, for instance*